# How do I replace Windows XP with Lubuntu?

Tags: windows, lubuntu, system-installation, windows-xp

I am rather a noob and have never installed anything before, but I would really like to completely replace my Windows XP with Lubuntu. I have saved all my photos and music already so that is sorted. The thing is I really don't know step-by-step what to do next. I have blank CDs and a USB all ready to go but what next? Please be gentle with me! (o:

Hey man thanks so much for the reply! I think in a normal world it would work brilliantly but sadly my computer is not living in the normal world. 
I followed you advice to the letter but I think perhaps because my computer is stuck in the loop of 'windows genuine notifications' it is blocking normal pathways. I do have genuine windows but it has apparently been a problem for a lot of people in the past and i tried for a few days last year to fix it with internet advice but it didn't take.

ANYHoo ... what has been happening is it all works until i get to where it is downloaded and i try to right click to copy or burn but it wants me to 'open with' and when I try to open it with something i have a limited list of things like 'firefox/explorer/winrar.exe/windows media player etc' if i try to 'open' it with firefox i get a blank page and nothing happens, if i try to open it with winrar i get a red 'x' sign, if i try to open it with anything windows based i get a 'windows genuine notifications' request which is impenetrable as i have learned over the years...
could you perhaps recommend something for me to download that would be an appropriate channel through which i can 'open' the downloaded file? if i can get past that i'm sure it would be smooth sailing.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1) Download the lubuntu .iso from http://lubuntu.net/. Choose 'x86 CD' if you have an older computer, and 64-bit only if you have a newer computer with 4gigs of RAM or more.

2) When its downloaded, right click on the .iso file, and chose to burn it to disc. If there is no option to do this, search for 'iso burning windows XP'

3) Leave the disc in after burning, and restart your machine. To boot from the disc, there is normally a key combination you'll need to do (like hold the 'escape' button). Again, you can search for this dependent on your computer.

4) Follow installation instructions and you're away. You'll find it amazingly fast compared to XP

Comment: Before burning the ISO you will want to check the MD5Sum of the download.  That will compare the downloaded ISO with the original image.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM  If the hashes match then proceed with the burn.  If not then you have a bad download and must download again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to burn the ISO to a CD.  Do not copy it.  You do not need to open it to burn it.  Just open up your CD burner and choose/add the ISO to burn.
Alternatively, download UNetbootin to burn the ISO to a flash/pen drive which will also make a bootable imagine.  You can download it here

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Instructions on how to can be found here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick